# Is it possible to swap passive for active cooling on this supermicro board?

Tags: heatsink, cpu-cooler, supermicro, mini-itx, passive-cooling

I'm looking to buy this Supermicro Mini-ITX board for an upcoming NAS build:
https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/A2SDi-H-TF

The only thing is, it has an integrated CPU with passive cooling - has anyone had success swapping the passive for an active cooler on these boards? I'm a newbie when it comes to supermicro - just wondering if this is a regular thing to do.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer is **NO**

Just looked at the supermicro store and there is no active cooler for this tipe of socket, simple because is a low TDP CPU (only 25W)

However you can DIY a Fan on top of the heatsink, or maybe hack a basic [Hyper 212X](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/coolers/cpu-air-coolers/hyper-212x/) to work for this motherboard.

the simple solution here is to attach a [small enough fan](https://noctua.at/es/nf-a6x25-pwm) to the heatsink so it can actively move fresh air to it

I personally will prefer to a attach the fan to the heatsink, i've done it before on other cpus and it works fine, provided if also your NAS case has fans too (at least 1)

Here are some of the pictures that i got

> [image]
>   [image]

You can find more related info here

[Source 1](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/supermicro-a2sdi-8c-hln4f-denverton-atom-c3758-w-gigabit.58344/page-3)

[Source 2](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/supermicro-xeon-d-1521-overheating-on-stress-tests.62130/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is the fan just sitting on top or is it attached to the heatsink somehow? I can't understand

Comment: @volothamp in the second photo the fan is screwed to the heatsink fins, the heatsink may not have the screw holes but it is possible to fix a fan to cool the chip. other options is to use zip ties.

Comment: I have an A2SDi-H-TF board and I swapped the passive cooler with an SNK-C0057A4L active cooler that bought from sbopblt. It seems to work just fine. It was a pain getting the passive cooler off (almost felt like it was glued on) but the new active cooler seems to fit perfectly.